# Why if/elsif in Perl execute only the first block?

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am new to Perl. I have an assignment to write a Perl program that accept a countable word from a command line and then generates its plural form. I have composed the following code below, and it shows no errors of compilation. When I execute it from the command line: 
(perl plural.pl, for example), it prompts me to enter a noun, then whatever noun I feed as input, the plural form is the same. It doesn't execute the remaining if statements.

For example, if I enter the word "cat", the plural is generated as "cats". But when I enter the word 'church', for example, the plural is generated as 'churches', "fly" as "flys".

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$suffix1 = 's';
$suffix2 = 'es';
$suffix3 = 'ies';

print "Enter a countable noun to get plural: ";
$word = <STDIN>;
chomp($word);

if(substr $word, -1 == 'b' or 'd' or 'c' or 'g' or 'r' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 't' or 'v' or 'w' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u') {
    $temp = $word.$suffix1;
    print "The plural form of the word \"$word\" is: $temp \n";
}
elsif (substr $word, -1 == 's' or 'sh' or 'ch' or 'x' or 'z') {
    $temp = $word.$suffix2;
    print "The plural form of the word \"$word\" is: $temp \n";
}
elsif (substr $word, -1 == 'y') {
    chop($word);
    $temp = $word.$suffix3;
    print "The plural form of the word \"$word\" is: $temp \n";
}
```

Could you help me making the code execute the three statements.

Comment: probably not applicable for an assignment, but: http://p3rl.org/Lingua::EN::Inflect#PL_N

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

- Strings are compared using `eq`, not `==`.
- `substr $word, -1 eq 'b'` means `substr $word, (-1 eq 'b')` when you meant `substr($word, -1) eq 'b'`. You'll face lots of problems if you omit parens around function calls.
- `substr($word, -1) eq 'b' or 'd'` means the same as `(substr($word, -1) eq 'b') or ('d')`. `'d'` is always true. You'd need to use `substr($word, -1) eq 'b' or substr($word, -1) eq 'd'`. (Preferably, you'd save `substr $word, -1` in a variable to avoid doing it repeatedly.)
- `substr $word, -1` will never equal `ch` or `sh`.

The match operator makes this easy:

```
if ($word =~ /[bdcgrjklmnpqrtvweiou]\z/) {
   ...
}
elsif ($word =~ /(?:[sxz]|[sc]h)\z/) {
   ...
}
elsif ($word =~ /y\z/) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I worked perfectly as I wanted. I did not know that PERL can write such short programs as the code you provided above. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! Thanks are also due to everyone who participated in this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Perl, we use `eq` for string comparison instead of `==`.
2. You can't use `or` like this. It should be like `if (substr($word, -1) eq 'b' or substr ($word, -1) eq 'd')`. Otherwise you could use an array containing all the string that you would like to compare and grep from that array.

Comment: Thank you duskast, I have edited the code as you noted above, but the program is giving wrong output. Please see demonstration of that:
mohammed@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ perl plural.pl

Enter a countable noun to get plural: duck

The plural form of the word "duck" is: ducks 

mohammed@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ perl plural.pl
Enter a countable noun to get plural: church
The plural form of the word "church" is: churchs 
mohammed@ubuntu:~/Desktop$

Comment: @Mohammed Answer updated, there're another problem in your code.

Comment: thank you for your correction, but I don't know how to do it using an array.

Comment: `substr $word, -1 eq 'b'` works out to be the same as `substr( $word, (-1 eq 'b') )`.

Comment: @Brad,  Thanks to both of you for kind help!

Comment: @duskast,  Thanks to both of you for kind help!

Answer (score 2):

Duskast is right.  Perl uses symbols for numeric comparisons, and strings for string comparisons.

```
==   eq
!=   ne
<    lt
<=   le
>    gt
>=   ge
<=>  cmp
```

Also, your use of `or`, though a good try, doesn't work.  The keyword `or`  has weak precedence, and so the expression

```
substr $word, -1 == 'b' or 'd' or 'c' or
                    'g' or 'r' or 'j' or
                    'k' or 'l' or 'm' or
                    'n' or 'p' or 'q' or
                    'r' or 't' or 'v' or
                    'w' or 'e' or 'i' or
                    'o' or 'u'
```

is interpreted as

```
substr ($word, (-1 == 'b')) or 'd' or 'c' or
                    'g' or 'r' or 'j' or
                    'k' or 'l' or 'm' or
                    'n' or 'p' or 'q' or
                    'r' or 't' or 'v' or
                    'w' or 'e' or 'i' or
                    'o' or 'u'
```

I'm not sure what the substr works out to, but if it's false, the expression continues to the `or 'b'`, which is interpreted as `true`.  Have you seen regular expressions yet? This is much more idiomatically done as

```
if ($word =~ /[bdcgrjklmnpqrtvweiou]$/) {...} 
# Does $word match any of those characters followed by
# the end of the line or string?
```

Look in the Perl docs for string substitution and the s/.../.../ construct.

By the way, if you were paid to do this instead of being a student, you'd use the Lingua modules instead.

Comment: See Lingua::EN::Inflect::Number. It has functions like `to_PL()` to pluralize English words, and `to_S()` to do the opposite. http://search.cpan.org/~simon/Lingua-EN-Inflect-Number-1.1/Number.pm

Comment: Sorry, Brad.  I didn't realize you were just posting a link that I should have posted.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eric Jablow, Thank you for elaborate explanation. I am a student, I never get paid for anything. If I get paid, it will be only in the form of marks. I did not look at regualar expressions. I am compeletely new to Perl. I could do the program in Python easily but the instructer's wish is to do it in Perl. You may see the influence of Python's syntax on my code. In Python, slicing s[-1] equals to Perl substr $variable -1. I can use the Lingua library, but the point is that students should get learning experience of composing simple programs. Thank you again.

Comment: Exactly.  One often performs tasks as a student that one would never do as a professional programmer or even as a professional in another field. For example, you may learn about sorting by learning to program a Bubble Sort, but in practice you would just use Perl's `sort` function.  I didn't know how much knowledge of the Perl ecology you had, and I agree with your instructor that you should program everything once by hand before resorting to libraries. After all, your routine deals only with regular nouns; it will not be able to deal with *mouse* and *mice* and similar word pairs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, always, always include `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Second, use indentations. I've taught Perl courses at work and refuse to accept any assignment that was not indented correctly. In fact, I'm very, very strict about this because I want users to learn to code to the standard (4 space indent, etc.). It makes your program easier to read and to support.

While we're at it, break overly long lines -- especially on StackOverflow. It's hard to read a program when you have to scroll back and forth.

Quick look at your program:

In Perl, strings and numerics use two different sets of boolean operations. This is because strings can contain only digits, but still be strings. Imagine inventory item numbers like `1384` and `993`. If I'm sorting these as strings, the `1384` item comes first. If I am sorting them numerically, `993` should come first. Your program has no way of knowing this except by the boolean operation you use:

```
Boolean Operation   Numeric  String
=================   =======  ======
Equals              ==       eq
Not Equals          !=       ne
Greater Than        >        gt
Less Than           <        lt
Greater than/Equals >=       ge
Less than/Equals    <=       le
```

THe other is that an `or`, `and`, `||` and `&&` only work with two booleans. This won't work:

```
if ( $a > $b or $c ) {
```

What this is saying is this:

```
if ( ( $a > $b ) or $c ) {
```

So, if `$c` is a non-zero value, then `$c` will be *true*, and the whole statement would be true. You have to do your statement this way:

```
if ( $a > $b or $a > $c ) {
```

Another thing, use `qq(..)` and `q()` when quoting strings that contain quotation marks. This way, you don't have to put a backslash in front of them.

```
print "The word is \"swordfish\"\n";

print qq(The word is "swordfish"\n);
```

And, if you use `use feature qw(say);` at the top of your program, you get the bonus command of `say` which is like `print`, except the ending new line is assumed:

```
say qq(The word is "swordfish");
```

When you use `substr, $foo, -1`, you are only looking at the last character. It cannot ever be a two character string:

```
if ( substr $word, -1 eq "ch" ) {
```

will always be false.

Long ifs are hard to maintain. I would use a `for loop` (actually not, but let's pretend for now..):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

#
# Use these in ALL of your programs
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

#
# Use better, more descriptive names
#
my $standard_plural_suffix = 's';
my $uncommon_plural_suffix = 'es';
my $y_ending_plural_suffix = 'ies';

print "Enter a countable noun to get plural: ";
chomp (my $word = <STDIN>);

my $plural_form;

#
# Instead of a long, long "if", use a for loop for testing. Easier to maintain
#
for my $last_letter qw( b d c g r j k l m n p q r t v w e i o u) {
    if ( substr($word, -1) eq $last_letter ) {
        $plural_form = $word . $standard_plural_suffix;
        last;
    }
}
#
# Is it an "uncommon plural" test (single character)
#
if ( not $plural_form ) {
    for my $last_letter qw(s x z) {
        if ( substr($word, -1) eq $last_letter ) {
            $plural_form = $word . $uncommon_plural_suffix;
            last;
        }
    }
}
#
# Is it an "uncommon plural" test (double character)
#
if ( not $plural_form ) {
    for my $last_two_letters qw(sh ch) {
        if ( substr($word, -2) eq $last_two_letters ) {
            $plural_form = $word . $uncommon_plural_suffix;
            last;
        }
    }
}
if ( not $plural_form ) {
    if ( substr($word, -1) eq 'y' ) {
        chop ( my $chopped_word = $word );
        $plural_form = $chopped_word . $y_ending_plural_suffix;
    }
}

if ( $plural_form ) {
    say qq(The plural of "$word" is "$plural_form");
}
else {
    say qq(Could not find plural form of "$word");
}
```

Do you know about regular expressions? Those would work a lot better than using `substr` because you can test multiple things at once. Plus, I wouldn't use `chop`, but a regular expression substitution:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

#
# Use these in ALL of your programs
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

#
# Use better, more descriptive names
#
my $standard_plural_suffix = 's';
my $uncommon_plural_suffix = 'es';
my $y_ending_plural_suffix = 'ies';

print "Enter a countable noun to get plural: ";
chomp (my $word = <STDIN>);

my $plural_form;

#
# Standard plural (adding plain ol' 's'
#
if ( $word =~ /[bdcgrjklmnpqrtvweiou]$/ ) {
    $plural_form = $word . $standard_plural_suffix;
}
#
# Uncommon plural (adding es)
#
elsif ( $word =~ /([sxz]|[sc]h)$/ ) {
    $plural_form = $word . $uncommon_plural_suffix;
}
#
# Final 'y' rule: Replace y with ies
#
elsif ( $word =~ /y$/ ) {
    $plural_form = $word;
    $plural_form =~ s/y$/ies/;
}

if ( $plural_form ) {
    say qq(The plural of "$word" is "$plural_form");
}
else {
    say qq(Could not find plural form of "$word");
}
```

Comment: [`use 5.12.0;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html "perldoc -f use") enables [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html "perldoc strict"), and [`feature ':5.12'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#FEATURE-BUNDLES "perldoc feature"), but it does not enable [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html "perldoc warnings").

Comment: @BradGilbert Dang it. You're right. I just started leaving out `use strict` and `use warnings` because I thought `use :5.12` would take care of it. I'll update my answer. I don't understand why strict would be enabled without warnings. Considering that warnings is way older and was implemented via `-W` since Perl 3.x. I remember that we should always have `#! /bin/perl -W` for the shebang.

Comment: @DavidW., Thank you so much for this interesting lesson and for the efforts you put in typing the corrected code to the webpage. There are many nice and helpful people around the world who extend a hand to anyone, no matter who they are. You  are one of those nice people. Besides, you are a competent teacher. My deepest thanks are also due to all who participated in the discussion of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a bit. I'm using regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$suffix1 = 's';
$suffix2 = 'es';
$suffix3 = 'ies';

print "Enter a countable noun to get plural: ";
$word = <STDIN>;
chomp($word);

if ( $word =~ m/(s|sh|ch|x|z)$/) {
    $temp = $word . $suffix2;
}
elsif ( substr( $word, -1 ) eq 'y' ) {
    chop($word);
    $temp = $word . $suffix3;
}
else {
    $temp = $word . $suffix1;
}

print "The plural form of the word \"$word\" is: $temp \n";
```

Also I recommend you always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: This is still broken. `substr $word, -1 eq 'y'` works out to be the same as `substr( $word, (-1 eq 'y') )`.